# Deck of Cards Probability question

Tags: probability

When randomly drawing 3 cards in sequence WITHOUT REPLACEMENT from a well shuffled standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability of a High card, then a Low card, then a High card?
I found that 52C3 is equal to 22100, which is the sample size 3 of the 52 cards, but I'm not sure where to continue from there.
Thanks!

Comment: How do you define "high card" and "low card" here?

Comment: As an aside, since the order of the cards matters here, you will not be using $\binom{52}{3}$ for the denominator but rather $52\cdot 51\cdot 50$ for the denominator.  Suppose that there are $h$ high cards and $l$ low cards.  What is the probability that the first card is a high card?  It would be $\frac{h}{52}$ right?  Now... given that the first card was a high card what is the probability that the second card is a low card?  $\frac{l}{51}$ since there are only 51 cards left.  What does multiplication principle tell you about probability of both happening?  Now as for the third card...

Comment: High card is 10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace

Comment: That helps a lot thank you!